# Multiplying probabilities by adding?

Tags: probability

Can you perform probability multiplication by addition?

Consider probabilities $a$ and $b$.

Can we find a function $f$ such that $f(a\cdot b) = f(a) + f(b)$?

Comment: What do you mean by f(a*b)?

Comment: Probabilities??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^r = a, e^s = b \Rightarrow e^{r+s} = ab.\;$ Thus, 
$\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b).$

Comment: Oh yes I also just found out by plugging it into wolframalpha, but thanks! This is the correct answer